# how to send object using postman rest client to call REST service so that it will hit the below given method with proper method parameters?

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-mvc, postman

I am tring to call a rest post method from postman. But I am not able to properly set the input parameters for method from postman.

NB : Please dont mark it as duplicate as this dosent have an existing answer in Stackoverflow.

Below the rest API code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/city/village/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateHome(@ModelAttribute final HomeAddress homeAddress,
            final HttpServletRequest request) {

            //// some code ///// 

            }



This is the HomeAddress class

public class HomeAddress{

  public String name;
  public int id;
  public List<String> membersName;


  getters.....
  setters....

  }
```

Please tell me how to send the request from Postman ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring by default your application will be running on `localhost:8080` -> then you can use your value `/city/village/home` -> `localhost:8080/city/village/home`.
You can take a look for example for Spring Boot Controller - https://adityasridhar.com/posts/how-to-create-simple-rest-apis-with-springboot

I'm not sure did you use `@Controller` annotation on the class and so on...
You can see how to use Postman here-> https://adityasridhar.com/posts/how-to-create-simple-rest-apis-with-springboot

You should use Json Format - you can validate it here : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
{
  "name": "NAme",
  "id": 5,
  "membersName": [
     "firstName",
    "secondName"
  ]
}
```

Comment: My doubt is how to call it from postman ? Should i use this Json in the body of the request ?

Comment: Yes, you need to put json in the 'Body' sector. In the 'Headers' sector you should put Key -> Content-Type and Value -> application/json